# jquery live() and plugins

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I am using the jquery plugin, uniform so that on my form I can have pretty radio buttons, and file inputs etc.

However I have hit a problem alot of my forms a pulled in via ajax, and obvioulsy for the plugin to work it needs to know that the elements exists in the dom.

Is there away to use plugins with ajax methods?

Currently I am trying,

`$(".uniform input").live().uniform();`

which obviously does not work, any suggestions?

---IMPLENTED IN LOAD CALLBACK-----

```
$('#upload').click(function(e) {
        $("#content #main").animate({"right": "-900px"}, 'slow', 'linear', function(){
            $(this).load('upload.html #main div', '', function(){
                $(".uploader input").uniform();
            });
        });
        $("#main").animate({"right": "0px"}, 'slow', 'swing');
        e.preventDefault();
    });
```

Comment: You need to modify the plugin.

Comment: I would suggest applying the plugins to the new forms before/after they are appended to the dom within the success method of the ajax call. .live() can only handle plugins that react to user interaction such as a click or a focus, it doesn't work very well with plugins that cause style changes on initialization.

Comment: @KevinB so with the ajax's callback?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In response to comments:

`.load` is nothing more than a `$.ajax` call wrapped in another method. It too has a callback.

```
$(target).load("myurl.php",function(){
  $("select").uniform();
});
```

Edit: i just saw your edit. If that isn't working, make sure you are using the correct selector to get to the elements you want to apply the plugin to.

Answer (score 1):

Just initialize uniform again **after** you've added in a form, using the normal

```
 $('#forms').append(new_selects_from_ajax);
 $("select").uniform();
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [livequery plugin](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/livequery), like this:

```
$('.uniform input').livequery(function(){
   $(this).uniform();
});
```

Comment: livequery has been entirely integrated into jQuery using `.live`, or so I thought.

Comment: Not completely, livequery has one thing jQuery doesn't have; detection of new elements being added to the dom. However, from what I've read, that functionality is not very efficient. All `.live` and `.delegate` do is delegate event binding.

Comment: @mblase75: Not according to the docs... from [API page](http://api.jquery.com/live/): "Description: Attach a handler to the **event** for all elements which match the current selector, now and in the future."

Answer (score 0):

One of the differnces between .live and .delegate is chainability.  Please review http://brandonaaron.net/blog/2010/03/4/event-delegation-with-jquery for a nice review on this.  This looks likely that you would use delegate in your situation.